# Managing dynamic height for UITableviewCell using iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I am trying out autoLayout features for dynamic height for UITableViewCell in iOS 8, I followed this blog http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/. So here they mention that from iOS 8 managing dynamic height is hassle free.(In the link they have used swift, but I am using objective C)

Now after doing autolayout from xib, then we need to just write this lines of code in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    m_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 83.0f;
    m_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

This is fine and my tableView height changes dynamically based on the content.

I want to know how to have more control on UITableViewCell height.

1) In my app, I want the cell height to be based on the content(data), but I need to have a default height, which will be applied if the content height is less than default height.

2) I want to know what will be the final height of the cell, before displaying to the user, because I want to add some UI elements below each cell.

So what functions I need to use to fulfil my tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make sure your Storyboard prototype cell has `NSLayoutConstraints` from top to bottom. Dynamic cell sizing compresses whatever layout constraints you have in place to their maximum compression given the content set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to calculate the final rendered height of that cell. It is very convenient but it also means you need to be careful about setting your constraints correctly.

If you are adding any subviews programmatically, you need to ensure the same rule of thumb is true- there is a complete, deterministic set of constraints from the top of your cell's contentView to the bottom. Additionally, you will need to set any subviews' added in code `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to `NO`.

Comment: Hello @Keller, I didnt get you properly